# scala count groupBy results

Tags: scala, group-by, rdd

I am a newbie to Scala, and I have the following question:

Say I have parsed in a text file with the following format:

```
RDD:[A , Apple, a fruit]
    [A , America, a country]
    [A , Africa, a continent]
    [B , Brazil, a country]
```

and I want to `groupBy` the alphabet sso that I have something like:

```
[A, Apple, a fruit, America, a country, Africa a continent]
```

I then want to take this and `groupBy` itself so that it gives me the string, and the count for each letter:

```
[A, a, 3
    fruit, 1
    America, 1
    Africa, 1]
```

so far my code looks like this:

```
val joined = parsed.groupBy(_._2).map((x)=>(x._1,x._2.map((y)=> y._1).toSeq))
val listtext = joined.map(x => x._2)
val idfs = listtext.groupBy(l => l).map(t => (t._1, t._2.size))
```

but the result is wrong, it seems to take `listtext` as one string, which results in the count always being 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your equation correctly you can do it this way:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("test")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  case class Input(letter: Char, text: String)
  case class Count(word: String, cnt: Long)
  case class Output(letter: Char, words: Seq[Count])

  val input: RDD[Input] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Input('A', "Apple, a fruit"),
    Input('A', "America, a country"),
    Input('A', "Africa, a continent"),
    Input('B', "Brazil, a country")
  ))

  val output: RDD[Output] = input.groupBy(_.letter) map  { case (letter, in) =>
    val cnt = collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Long]
    in.flatMap(_.text.replaceAll(",", "").split(" ").toSeq).foreach { word =>
      cnt.put(word, cnt.getOrElse(word, 0l) + 1)
    }
    val words = cnt map { case (word, n) => Count(word, n) }
    Output(letter, words.toSeq.sortBy(_.cnt).reverse)
  }

  output.collect().foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
Output(B,ArrayBuffer(Count(a,1), Count(country,1), Count(Brazil,1)))
Output(A,ArrayBuffer(Count(a,3), Count(Apple,1), Count(Africa,1), Count(country,1), Count(continent,1), Count(fruit,1), Count(America,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply chain a few transformations/combinators to achieve this:

```
val arr = Array(("A" , "Apple", "a fruit"),
                ("A" , "America", "a country"),
                ("A" , "Africa", "a continent"),
                ("B" , "Brazil", "a country"))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)

val r1 = rdd.groupBy(x => x._1) 
// (A => ((A, Apple, a fruit), (A, America, a country), ...)           

val r2 = r1.map{ case (x, y) => (x, y.flatMap{ case (a, b, c) => Array(b, c) }
                                     .mkString(" ")) }
// A => "Apple a fruit America a country Africa a continent", B => ...

r2.map { case (x, y) => (x, y.split(" ")
                            .groupBy(x => x)
                            .map{ case (a, b) => (a, b.size) })}
  .collect

// Array((A, Map(fruit -> 1, a -> 3, country -> 1, Apple -> 1, continent -> 1, America -> 1, Africa -> 1)), (B,Map(Brazil -> 1, country -> 1, a -> 1)))
```